# None of any chatting apps shows contact list

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, contacts, whatsapp-messenger, permissions

Today I updated my Lenovo `A6000Plus` to `Lolipop` Via `OTA`

Now I am suffering from a very weird problem.

WhatsApp Hike doesn't show any contacts in List. Although When I open my contact List I can see all of my contacts.

What I tried :

1. Checked the permission of each app. Every app is allowed to read contacts.
2. Rebooted my device
3. Removed my google account and sign in again
4. Navigated to whatsApp setings->contacts their Show all contact is already Checked.

All these methods doesn't work

Whenever anyone message me on hike or whatsapp i only see the number.Even When I add that Number I am not able to see the name.

I googled but nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

Now I realized no one can help you except yourself.

Finally i Found a way.

> Navigate to Settings - > Apps - > All Apps
>
> Search For contact and Contact Storage
>
> Clear Both Apps Data

Booom You Are Done.....

**Note**
Clearing Contact and Contact Storage Erase Your all Contact SO make Sure you backed up your all contact online or somemwhere else. In my case I use google account.

Comment: Your contacts would've been erased if you did clear "Contact Storage". Did you backup them earlier? I think so, but please mention that in the answer.

Comment: @Firelord Yes my all contacts are backed up in google....